# How to Read response if "response.isSuccessful()" is true in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

JSON Response from API:

```
{
    "type": "loginResponseMessage",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusMessage": "Login Successful",
    "resource_id": 3
}
```

I want to read JSON response. When 'if(response.isSuccessful())' is executing I am getting null pointer exception. In case of execution of 'else' block I am getting correct response. Following is the code:

```
@Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                LoginResponseMessage loginResponseMessage;

                loginResponseMessage = new APIResponse().getResponse2(retrofit,response);

                String toastMessage = "StatusMessage: "+loginResponseMessage.getStatusMessage()
                        +"Status Code: "+loginResponseMessage.getStatusCode()
                        +"ResourceId: "+loginResponseMessage.getResource_id();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                switch(response.code()){
                    case 401:
                        LoginResponseMessage loginResponseMessage;

                        loginResponseMessage = new APIResponse().getResponse2(retrofit,response);

                        String toastMessage = "StatusMessage: "+loginResponseMessage.getStatusMessage()
                                +"Status Code: "+loginResponseMessage.getStatusCode()
                                +"ResourceId: "+loginResponseMessage.getResource_id();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Class APIResponse:

```
public class APIResponse {
    private String statusMessage;

    public LoginResponseMessage getResponse2(Retrofit retrofit, Response response){         //This will only be called in LoginActivity
        LoginResponseMessage responseMessage = new LoginResponseMessage();

        Converter<ResponseBody, LoginResponseMessage> converter
                = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(LoginResponseMessage.class, new Annotation[0]);
        try {
            responseMessage = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseMessage;
    }
}
```

Same logic is applied in 'if' & 'else' block. But getting null pointer exception in 'if (response.isSuccessful())' block

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Reader okhttp3.ResponseBody.charStream()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:35)
                                                                      at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
                                                                      at pk.qareeb.qareeb.LoginActivity$5.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:206)
                                                                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
t
```

**2nd Approach:**
I have also tried following code.

```
@Override
     public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response.body().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

By adding 2nd approach code, instead of toasting JSON response, it is toasting "com.qareeb.qareeb.modal.Login@119c611". Why ?

Comment: second options returns that text because you are trying to print out an object for which the system does not know how to use the `toString()` method. So for non-primitive objects if you want to use `toString()` you need to override `toString()` method in the object class, in your case in `Login` class. 

For the first approach you need to share the new `APIResponse().getResponse2()` function code as well. Probably there is an issue with that

Comment: `JSONObject object=new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: "+object );` to read the response

Comment: @insa_c apologize I missed to add getResponse2(). Now I have edited question, please check.

Comment: @VishalYadav I have tried your solution. Still getting empty response. 

Logcat Result:
onResponse: {}

Comment: Try to debug you LOC

Comment: what was inside your login class `Login` post the response

Comment: @VishalYadav Response is already posted at top of Question.
Login class has String email_address, String password.
But response from API has attributes type, statusCode, statusMessage & resource_Id. To handle API response I have class LoginResponseMessage which has fields: type, statusCode, statusMessage & resource_Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Second approach** you are printing the `instance of Login class`. it's not an error or issue. If you want to see the response then override the **toString()** method inside your **Login** class or you can also check the properties inside your **Login** class one by one.

**Edit-**
As I understand you are using Login(for request) class here instead of a Response(to get the response) class. So use your Login class to send a request and LoginResponse class to get the login response.

Make a separate class name **LoginResponse** and use it instead of **Login** in your network call.

**LoginResponse.java**

```
public class LoginResponse
{
   private String statusCode;

   private String resource_id;

   private String type;

    private String statusMessage;
    // getter and setters.
    .
    .
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "LoginResponse [statusCode = "+statusCode+", resource_id = "+resource_id+", type = "+type+", statusMessage = "+statusMessage+"]";
    }
}
```

**Now do it like-**

```
@Override
 public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
     Toast.makeText(context, LoginResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

**Or**

```
@Override
 public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
     LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
     Toast.makeText(context, loginResponse.getStatusMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Toast.makeText(context, loginResponse.getType (), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: Not working. because Login Class has only String email_address, String password. But response from API has attributes type, statusCode, statusMessage & resource_Id. To handle API response I have class LoginResponseMessage which has fields: type, statusCode, statusMessage & resource_Id.

Comment: I think you are calling it wrong, use Call<Login> to request for login, and make a separate class to get the login response e.g.- Call<LoginResponse>, check the updated answer.

Comment: I have got your point. But the issue is: In request API needs Login object (which consists of email address & password only).
Request is process at server & returns JSON response. Which has attributes of Class LoginResponse (which consists of type, statusCode, statusMessage & resource_Id). Request & Response objects are different.
But:
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) { //CODE }
accepts same object for call & response. How to solve it?

Comment: Is it possible for you to come on skype ? So, I would do screen sharing with you . Actually, I have already spend lot of time in fixing this issue, and due to this I can't proceed further. And I am short of deadline

Comment: If its possible for you to come on skype so please find me on skype using datakz2018@gmail.com